# uploaded my Build to the App Store but still getting error message

Tags: app-store

I uploaded the Build of my App (in Xcode, 'Product' then 'Archive', then 'Upload to App Store'). But when I go back to iTunes Connect and press 'Submit for Review' the web page is telling me that I have not yet uploaded the Build.

Can anyone please tell me what I need to do?

Comment: Have you tried another browser?

Comment: Did you select the build you uploaded in the App Info page before submitting?